# My console crash if i use this function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, crash, codeblocks

I am creating app that can draw to console but my console crashs
i tested my draw code and it works fine. (I created it in codeblocks)

> if i try to run function `rect()`

Please help i dont know what to do to make it work.
(I was programing in javascript(p5*.js) and that was easier)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define WIDTH 80
#define HEIGHT 40 

using namespace std;

//just including basic stuff please try to make solution without including more lib.

int grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
int x, y, xp, xs, yp, ys, n;
int length = HEIGHT * WIDTH;
void printarray()
{
    //it will print array when it is called in to the console
    for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
        {
            /*if (grid[y][x]%2 == 0){      //just test
                 printf("#");
             }else{
                 printf("_");
             }
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

     for (int n=0; n<WIDTH; ++n){
         printf("=");
     }
     printf("\n");
}*/
            if (grid[y][x] == 1)
            {
                //it just dicide if it draw # or _
                printf("#");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("_");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < WIDTH; ++n)
    {
        printf("=");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void rect(int xp, int yp, int xs, int ys)
{
    //it should print rectangle
    for (y = yp; y < yp + ys; y++)
    {
        //xp is position on x
        grid[y][xp] = 1; //xs is how long is on x
        grid[y][xp - xs] = 1; //every loop set 2 lines in array grid[][]
    }
    for (x = xp; x < xp + xs; x++)
    {
        grid[yp][x] = 1;
        grid[yp - ys][x] = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{ //main function
    for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
        {
            //grid[y][x] = x+y*(WIDTH-1); //just part of test
            grid[y][x] = 0;
            rect(2, 2, 3, 5); //if i call this function my console crash or dont do anything
        } //and it sometimes write in my build log Process terminated with status -1073741510
    printarray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code badly needs to be formatted.

Comment: hint: what is `xp-xs` when you call the function? which element is `grid[y][xp-xs]` ? Time for you to learn how a debugger works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your indexing in `rect()`.

For `rect(2, 2, 3, 5)`, `xp-xs` is `-1` and `yp-ys` is `-1` too.  So `grid[y][xp-xs]` and `grid[yp-ys][x]` are out of bounds.  So it's UB, hence the observed crash in some cases but not always.

You should correct the loops:  either go from zp to zs or from zp to zp+zs (depending if xs,ys are coordinates of the opposite point, or if xs and ys are width of the rectangle).  For example:

```
void rect (int xp, int yp, int xs, int ys) {
  for (y=yp; y<=yp+ys; y++) {
    //xp is position on x
    grid[y][xp]=1; //xs is how long is on x
    grid[y][xp+xs]=1; //every loop set 2 lines in array grid[][]
  }
  for (x=xp; x<=xp+xs; x++) {
    grid[yp][x]=1;
    grid[yp+ys][x]=1;
  }
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/LiTzbf)